# html & django resize img-parent div to one size

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

In my application I let the user upload images. They are all displayed in a grid system. But because of there different aspect ratio it´s of course not possible that they have the same size. Are there any possibilities although the images aren´t the same size but let the parent-div be the same size for all projects. Thanks

here is my template

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for project in projects %}
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="border border-dark">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{project.featured_images.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <h5 class="text-center">{{project.title}}</h5>
                  </a>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
                      <li class="list-group-item flex-fill">{{project.price}} €</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item flex-fill">{{project.location}}</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a little bit of CSS. Add a certain height of the image (`.card-img-top`) and add `object-fit: contain` like this:

```css
.card-img-top {
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

If you want that the image always start from top and not from center use `object-position: top`:

```css
.card-img-top {
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top;
}
```